# HikariCP connection pooling multitenancy datasource

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, hikaricp

I'm implementing a multtitenancy strategy where every tenant has it's own database.
I'm running everything agains a postgresql database.
To get a DataSource per tenant I'm extending AbstractDataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl.

Problem:
Every generated Datasource uses it's own connection pool.
After a couple of created tenant I cant't get a a new connection because postgres says I have already to many connections.

e.g: 10 Tenants with a maxpoolsize of 10 => 100 connections.
The 101 connection could not be opened.

Can I use a shared connection pool between all datasources so that the maximumpool of 10 is applied to all datasources and not only one?
Is there any better approach?

Thanks for all help!